# "Type mismatch" error when iterating through fields of ADODB recordset

Tags: vba, excel, adodb

`Sheet1` of a workbook has the following values in cells `A1:C2`:

```
abc  def  ghi
123  456  789
```

I'm opening this sheet in an ADODB recordset and reading fields using the following code:

```
Public Sub printColumnHeaders()

Dim fld As field

'class for handling ADODB operations
Dim ac As ADOConnector

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

Set ac = New ADOConnector

'establish ADODB.Connection
ac.connect "T:\test\testADO.xlsx"

'open recordset of Sheet1
Set rs = ac.selectSQL("select * from [Sheet1$]")

rs.MoveFirst

'test if recordset has been successfully opened
'by checking individual value
Debug.Print rs.Fields(0).Name
Debug.Print rs.Fields(0).value

For Each fld In rs.Fields
    Debug.Print fld.value
Next

End Sub
```

This successfully prints:

```
abc
123
```

but then throws an error on the `For Each fld In rs.Fields`:

```
Type mismatch
```

When I right-click on `field` and select "Definition", I get this message:

```
Identifier under cursor is not recognized
```

I have the following relevant references enabled:

```
Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Microsoft Office 14.0 Access database engine Object Library
Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library
Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Recordset 6.0 Library
Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library
```

When I'm declaring the variable `fld` by typing the `Dim` statement, when I type `As` I get Intellisense that includes the word `Field`, so the object is known at that level.

What's especially strange is that I copied the code for `ADOConnector` from another VBA application that includes an identical `For each fld in rs.Fields` iteration, and this other application has all the same references enabled and displays the same `Identifier under cursor is not recognized` message, but successfully iterates the through the Fields collection. I haven't been able to figure out what difference, if any, there is between these two applications.

Comment: What if you use `Dim fld As ADODB.Field` instead of `Dim fld As field`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, declaring it as `ADODB.Field` resolved the issue.  Not sure why I needed to do that with this app and not with the other one.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, if you want to post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like `field` was not resolved as an object of type `ADODB.Field`

So change this:

```
Dim fld As field
```

to this:

```
Dim fld As ADODB.Field
```

This probably has something to do with referencing two libraries that both have objects called 'field' in them:

> > Microsoft Office 14.0 Access database engine Object Library
> >
> > Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library